# Import “User32.DLL” in Windows Service Program

Tags: windows, service

I want to use the User32.DLL method `LockWorkStation()` to lock my computer in from windows service, but it doesn't work. The code is like that:

```
[DllImport("User32.DLL")]
    public static extern void LockWorkStation(); 

    public static void LockPC()
    {
        LockWorkStation();
    }
```

which I use in windows form program is successful.

I want to know when I want to import `User32.DLL` in my service program, what I need to do.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Windows has, for a long time, supported there being *multiple* users logged on. And services don't run in the same session as *any* of those logged in users. Stop going down this current (broken) path and tell us what the overall problem is that you're trying to solve, that you *thought* the solution involved having a service locking the computer?

Comment: That locks the work station for session 0, the isolated session that services run in.  That could have interesting side-effects, certainly none that you'd ever actually want.  Locking the user's work station from a service makes no sense.

Comment: To expand on the existing answers, what you need to do is to have your service launch a process in the user's session, in order to call `LockWorkStation` on your behalf.  There are existing questions and answers on how to do this, though be warned that it isn't trivial.

Comment: Thanks, I hava done it